# React button to show an element

Tags: reactjs

I'm pulling countries from the Restcountries API and if the current state of the array has more than one or less than or equal to ten countries, I want to list the country names along with a 'show' button next to each one. The show button should display what's in the return (render) of my `Country` function. In the `App` function, I wrote a handler for the button named `handleViewButton`. I'm confused on how to filter the element in the `Countries` function in the `else` conditional statement in order to display the `Country`. I tried passing `handleViewButton` to the `Button` function, but I get an error 'Uncaught TypeError: newSearch.toLowerCase is not a function'. I really just want to fire the `Country` function to display the country button that was pressed.

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const Country = ({country}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <h2>{country.name}</h2>
                <p>capital {country.capital}</p>
                <p>population {country.population}</p>
            <br/>
            <h3>languages</h3>
                {country.languages.map(language => <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>)}
            <br/>
            <img src={country.flag} alt="country flag" style={{ width: '250px'}}/>
        </>
    );
}

const Countries = ({countries, handleViewButton}) => {    
    const countriesLen = countries.length;
    console.log(countriesLen)

    if (countriesLen === 0) {
        return (
           <p>Please try another search...</p>
        );
    } else if (countriesLen === 1) {
        return (
           <ul>
                {countries.map((country, i) => <Country key={i} countriesLen={countriesLen} country={country}/>)}
           </ul>
        );
    } else if (countriesLen > 10) {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <ul>
                {countries.map((country, i) => <li key={i}>{country.name}<Button handleViewButton={handleViewButton}/></li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    };
};

const Button = ({handleViewButton}) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={handleViewButton}>Show</button>
    );
};

const Input = ({newSearch, handleSearch}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            find countries <input value={newSearch} onChange={handleSearch}/>
        </div>
    );
};

function App() {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
    const [newSearch, setNewSearch] = useState('');

    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        const search = event.target.value;
        setNewSearch(search);
    };

    const handleViewButton = (event) => {
        const search = event.target.value;
        setNewSearch(countries.filter(country => country === search));
    };

    const showCountrySearch = newSearch
        ? countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().includes(newSearch.toLowerCase()))
        : countries;

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
            .then(res => {
                setCountries(res.data);
                console.log('Countries array loaded');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
            })
    }, []);

    return ( 
        <div>
            <Input newSearch={newSearch} handleSearch={handleSearch}/>
            <Countries countries={showCountrySearch} handleViewButton={handleViewButton}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `displayCountry` to handle the country that should be displayed. Most often you would use an id, but I'm using here `country.name` since it should be unique.

Then you would use `matchedCountry` to find against your list of countries.

After that, a `onHandleSelectCountry` to select a given country. if it's already selected then you could set to `null` to unselect.

Finally, you would render conditionally your `matchedCountry`:

```
const Countries = ({countries}) => {
    const [displayCountry, setDisplayCountry] = useState(null); 
    const countriesLen = countries.length;
    
    const matchedCountry = countries.find(({ name }) => name === displayCountry); 

    const onHandleSelectCountry = (country) => {
      setDisplayCountry(selected => { 
        return selected !== country.name ? country.name : null
      })
    }


    if (countriesLen === 0) {
        return (
           <p>Please try another search...</p>
        );
    } else if (countriesLen === 1) {
        return (
           <ul>
                {countries.map((country, i) => <Country key={i} countriesLen={countriesLen} country={country}/>)}
           </ul>
        );
    } else if (countriesLen > 10) {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
          <>
            <ul>
                {countries.map((country, i) => <li key={i}>{country.name}<Button handleViewButton={() => onHandleSelectCountry(country)}/></li>)}
            </ul>
            { matchedCountry && <Country countriesLen={countriesLen} country={matchedCountry}/> }
          </>
        )
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, buzatto, that worked. I have one question. Why did you put `name` in curly braces in the `find` method for `matchedCountry`? Ex. `countries.find(({ name }) => name === displayCountry);` Does that look for `name` directly in the `countries` object?

Comment: In some sense yes. Since country it is an object, you can use this syntax to extract its properties. You can extract multiples properties, this way writing a cleaner code. You can look more info about searching for "destructuring javascript Es6"

Comment: If you look at your code you do the same thing I do at your components where you destruct props to extract country , that's an object.

Answer (score 0):

I can only help to point out some guidelines.

**First**: The button does not have value attribute. Hence what you will get from *event.target.value* is always blank.

```
const Button = ({handleViewButton}) => {
return (
    <button onClick={handleViewButton}>Show</button>
);};
```

**First->Suggestion**: Add value to the button, of course you need to pass the value in.

```
const Button = ({handleViewButton, value}) => {
return (
    <button onClick={handleViewButton} value={value}>Show</button>
);};
```

**Second**: To your problem 'Uncaught TypeError: newSearch.toLowerCase is not a function'. Filter always returns an array, not a single value. if you do with console or some sandbox [1,2,3].filter(x=>x===2) you will get [2] not 2.

```
const handleViewButton = (event) => {
    const search = event.target.value;
    setNewSearch(countries.filter(country => country === search));
};
```

**Second->Suggestion**: To change it to get the first element in array, since country(logically) is unique.

```
const result = countries.filter(country => country === search)
setNewSearch(result.length>0?result[0]:"");
```

A better approach for array is find, which always return first result and as a value. E.g. [1,2,2,3].find(x=>x===2) you will get 2 not [2,2] or [2].

```
countries.find(country => country === search)
```